# java.lang.stackoverflowerror recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static boolean sum_rec(int[] A, int n, int k) {

    return addition(A, n, k, 0);

} // end sum_rec

private static boolean addition(int[] A, int n, int k, int i) {

    if (k == A[i] + A[n - 1 - i]) {

        return true;
    }
    else if (n == 1){

        return false;
    }
    else
        return addition(A, n, k, i++);
}
```

Hi, I am getting stackoverflow error whenever I try to run the following code. It returns true if there are any two numbers in array that sum up to a value k but I cant seem to find the error. Any help will be appreciated. Also what is the running time of this?

Comment: Your recursion never ends. You are sending to recurson with single modified parameter and don't have inside your code an option to stop this. And in my oppinion, for significant array sizes it is better to run for-loop or use java8 streams

Comment: so what condition should I put?

Comment: Just think about - do you have elements in array with negative index?

Comment: No there are no negative elements

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin Check the code carefully: it actually calls the method with **no** modified parameters.  (Which makes sense, because if it did call it with a modified parameter, it would result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` before a stack overflow, right?  Unless `n` is huge.)

Comment: Input, results, and Expected Results are needed. This question likely closes as lacking an  MCVE. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You need a base case that will end the recursion (return false) in the case that

```
k == A[i]+A[n-1-i]
```

is never true.

n == 1 is not that base case since n doesn't change during the recursion ... a base case that depends on the variable that changes during recursion

Comment: can u help me with the base case? I cant figure it out

Comment: 1. How about if you take two pointers one to the start of the array the other to the end of the array
2.Add both the elements array[start] + array[end]
3. if sum > k then decrement "end" (end-1) else increment "start"
Repeat step2 and step3 till start= end

Comment: @RYS221 I didn't see anywhere in the question where the OP said the array was sorted.  Also, this is Java so "pointer" is a dirty word.

Comment: Sorry. Two integers i=0 and j=n-1, the values of the first and last index. Yeah if the array wasn't sorted it wouldn't work

Comment: the array is sorted in increasing order

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.  One that hasn't been pointed out yet is that you think you're calling the method recursively by adding 1 to the last parameter, but you're not.  This line:

```
return addition(A, n, k, i++);
```

has a post-increment operator.  This means that it will add 1 to `i` **but it will use the old value of `i`** as the parameter.  So it's the same as:

```
int oldValueOfI = i;
i = i + 1;
return addition(A, n, k, oldValueOfI);
```

You can see that you're calling the method recursively with the exact same values that it was called last time, so of course it will recurse infinitely.  Although I wouldn't use recursion for this program, if you really want to, change the call to

```
return addition(A, n, k, i + 1);
```

You're not going to use `i` afterwards, so you don't need to change the value.  (Note that each recursive call has its own `i` variable; the variable is not shared between the calls.  So incrementing `i` will not have any impact on the `i` used by the next recursive call, the previous recursive call, or any other recursive call.)

Also note that this will not solve your problem, but making this change might help you figure out what to do next when your program starts blowing up on a different exception.